# Pytorch: Training loss not decreasing in VAE

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have implemented a Variational Autoencoder model in Pytorch that is trained on SMILES strings (String representations of molecular structures).
While training the autoencoder to output the same string as the input, the Loss function does not decrease between epochs.

I have tried the following with no success:
1) Adding 3 more GRU layers to the decoder to increase learning capability of the model.
2) Increasing the latent vector size from 292 to 350.
3) Increasing and decreasing the learning rate.
4) Changing the optimizer from Adam to SGD.
5) Trained the model on upto 50 epochs.
6) Increasing and decreasing the batch size.

The following is the link to my code.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LctSm_Emnn5sHpw_Hon8xL5fF4bmKRw5

The following is an equivalent keras model(Same architecture) that is able to train successfully.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/170Peseik03CFYpWPNyD8B8mxUGxTQx67

Comment: Just as a suggestion from my experience: You first might to get it working without the "Variational", i.e. the sampling and KL divergence, etc. VAEs can be very finicky.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried training the model without the "Variational" parts. The loss is still not changing between epochs. So, the problem is probably with the encoder and decoder parts itself or might be arising from my training loop. I'm really not sure.

Comment: I had a second look at your code, but it's not obvious what might be wrong. One thing that strikes me is odd is in the decoder. Why is there any need to repeat a tensor in the `forward` method. Intuitively, the flattening in the encoder (you use `view`) and the un-flattening in the decoder should be mirroring steps. I have a (kind of) working implementation of a Text CNN VAE: https://github.com/chrisvdweth/ml-toolkit/blob/master/pytorch/models/text/autoencoder/textcnnvae.py Please note that I use `view` for flattening (encoder) and un-flattening (decoder).

Comment: Repeating the vector is suggested here for sequence-to-sequence autoencoders.  
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html  
The reasons for the repetition are answered to some extent in the following issue.  
So, it does seem as though it might not affect the training as much.  
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5203

Comment: Are you suggesting view followed by deconv instead of repeating the vector?

Comment: OK, my bad. I actually didn't notice that you use a CNN encoder but RNN decoder. Autoencoders typically have a symmetric architecture, including all the examples in the Keras blog you've linked. While you can technically do what you're doing, it's not a traditional (v)ae autoencoder anymore. I'm not familiar with Keras enough to see the need for repeating tensors in the RNN example in Keras blog.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem today. KL loss was decreasing, but recreation loss was not. After following the suggestion by ptrblck on (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/vae-loss-not-decreasing/47857), I figured I had forgotten to add the decoder parameters during the optimizer initialization :| Hope this can help someone in the future. PS: Please don't judge me for the crazy mistake :)